# 'Document matching query does not exist in django-celery

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to run a async task using django-celery and I am not sure why it keeps coming with this error.

So, my setup is as follows:

I have installed `redis` as the messaging service and I can verify that it is running. My `settings.py` file has the following lines related to django-celery:

```
import djcelery
# Setup celery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myproject.tasks", )
```

I have the celery worker running as:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info -E -B
```

This returns

```
 -------------- celery@gsp v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7f8aab484da0 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . myproject.tasks.add
  . myproject.tasks.generate_cbf_maps
  . myproject.tasks.sleeptask
```

One of the models is defined as:

```
class LabelModel(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/label',
                             db_column='path', default='Some Value')
```

This is referred to by another model as:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    labelled_image = models.ForeignKey(LabelModel, db_column='label')
```

Now, one of the celery tasks is defined as:

```
@celery.task
def generate_cbf_maps(document_id):
    obj = Document.objects.get(pk=document_id)
```

and when I call this from my view, it barfs with `myproject.myapp.models.DoesNotExist: Document matching query does not exist.`. If I look in the sqlite3 database, I can see that this key exists but somehow it is unable to find it.

Additionally, if I just do this in my `view`, it is fine. So a call like:

```
obj = Document.objects.get(pk=document_id)
```

This is fine in my `views.py` file but when I call it from within the celery task, it does not work.

I am not sure if I have to do something to configure this so called result broker. I tried things like:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis'
```

but it does not help.

Comment: did you include future imports in your __init__.py file ?

Comment: @sebb Which __init__.py file do I need to put this in? I have not done it. Did not know I had to. I am also on Pyhton 3.5, django 1.10

Comment: Let's say you have your project/project/celery.py and stuff. in the same folder as celery.py create a file named __ init__.py and put this inside:

from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa

Comment: I do not have celery.py file at all. I am using the django-celery package and I was under the impression that `djcelery.setup_loader()` takes care of this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to put in my `settings.py` file:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Then it works fine.